# Why does my hot cooktop indicator light stay on after the cooktop is cool? The indicator light now wont turn off

Tags: stove

My alamna Range electric smoothtop stove, on indicator light I just noticed tonight now stays on after everything has cooled down. Is this safe? Is it okay to just leave it, it still works fine.

Comment: Does the light ever turn off, or is it always on?  What is the ambient temperature where the range is? Have you contacted Alamna?

Answer (score -2):

To quote from Amana documentation:

> Many smoothtop models have indicator lights that may stay on after the
>   burner has been turned off. The light will go off after the burner
>   surface has cooled to a safe temperature. This is normal operation.

Comment: The OP stated that it is now staying on **after** everything has cooled down.

Comment: @DoxyLover Yeah, well, maybe the burner is not actually fully cold yet and the guy is just jumping the gun, that's my guess.